# Expanding variables in command line

Tags: bash, zenity

In short I want to produce this kind of a list
[image]

```
for file in *
do
    woC=$(sed -n -e 's#some-regex#\1#p' "$file")
    idL=$(pcregrep -M  '/some-regex/\1/p')
    gridData="$gridData $file $wowC \"$idL\""
done
```

Pretend that what's inside  $woC and $idL is not important. What's important is that $idL might contain white space.

```
zenity --list \
  --title="NCR Service Requests" \
  --width=420 --height=500 \
  --column="File" --column="Wow Code" --column="ID list" \
  $gridData
```

I cannot figure out how to force bash to expand $gridData (or $idL, I don't know where exactly is the problem) in such a way, that whitespace be preserved, yet separate fields remain separate.

Comment: If `idL` needs to be separate whitespace-containing arguments (to `zenity`) then you need to use an array (and cannot use `pcregrep` to populate it unless you have a way to loop in the shell to split it the way you want).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs`:

> xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks
>   (which can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash)
>   or newlines, and executes the command...

You would build the complete list of arguments and pass it to `zenity`:

```
#!/bin/bash
gridData="\"a b\" \"c\" \"d\""
gridData="$gridData \"a\" \"b c\" \"d\""
gridData="$gridData \"a\" \"b\" \"c d\""

echo "--list 
--title=\"NCR Service Requests\"
--width=420 --height=500
--column=\"File\"
--column=\"Wow Code\"
--column=\"ID list\" $gridData" | xargs zenity

exit 0
```